# RestKit create mapping for nested array

Tags: multidimensional-array, nested, restkit

I'm using Rest Kit to parse data from the server. 
I have this JSON from the server:

```
{
  "title":""
  "data":
    {
      "container":
                 [
                   {
                     "container_award":
                       [[[{"title":"","image":""}]]]
                   }
                 ],...
    }
}
```

I need to create the mapping to do this.
My problem is in creating the Mapping for the `container_award`, because i don't know how to get the nested arrays in the mapping for Rest Kit.

There is my mapping, but doesn't work:

```
RKObjectMapping *responseMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[Card class]];

[responseMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[Card getMapping]];


// if we have keyPath we also cold have subKeyPath

RKObjectMapping *cardContainerArrayMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CardContainerArray class]];

RKObjectMapping *cardContainerMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CardContainer class]];
[cardContainerMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[CardContainer getMapping]];

RKObjectMapping *containerDataMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CardContainerData class]];
[containerDataMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[CardContainerData getMapping]];


// for three array
RKObjectMapping *containerDataAwardsMapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[CardContainerData class]];
[containerDataAwardsMapping addAttributeMappingsFromDictionary:[CardContainerData getMapping]];

RKObjectMapping *array1Mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSArray class]];
[array1Mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil
                                                                              toKeyPath:nil
                                                                            withMapping:containerDataAwardsMapping]];


RKObjectMapping *array2Mapping = [RKObjectMapping mappingForClass:[NSArray class]];
[array2Mapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:nil
                                                                              toKeyPath:nil
                                                                            withMapping:array1Mapping]];

[cardContainerMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"container_awards"
                                                                                     toKeyPath:@"container_awards"
                                                                                   withMapping:array2Mapping]];

[cardContainerArrayMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"containers"
                                                                                toKeyPath:@"containers"
                                                                              withMapping:cardContainerMapping]];

[responseMapping addPropertyMapping:[RKRelationshipMapping relationshipMappingFromKeyPath:@"data"
                                                                                toKeyPath:@"data"
                                                                              withMapping:cardContainerArrayMapping]];
```

Edit:
The Card Class

```
@class CardContainerArray;

@interface Card : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic,strong) CardContainerArray *data;
```

The CardContainerArray Class:

```
@interface CardContainerArray : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *container;

@end
```

The CardContainer Class:
    @interface CardContainer : NSObject

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray*  container_award;
```

And the CardContainerData:

```
@interface CardContainerData : NSObject

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;
@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *image;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a 'container' class to handle the `container` in your JSON, because you can't index into an array as part of the mapping. That 'container' could be a custom class, or it could be a simple dictionary, it depends how you want the final data to be.

You can alternatively map `container` into an array on your existing class and then handle the array of dictionaries yourself.

`[[[{"title":"","image":""}]]]` is pretty rubbish though, that should really be cleaned up as a triple nested array seems illogical...

---

From your edit, you don't really want to be mapping into `NSArray`. At best it should be `NSMutableArray`, but you don't map arrays, you map the contents of arrays.

---

Dealing with `[[[{"title":"","image":""}]]]`:

probably the easiest option is to cheat... You already have `@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *title;` and `@property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *image;`, but don't use that in the mapping. Instead, make the mapping simply `imageMessyArray` and use:

```
- (NSArray *)imageMessyArray { return @[]; }
- (void)setImageMessyArray:(NSArray *)messyArray {
    NSDictionary *imageDict = [[[messyArray firstObject] firstObject] firstObject];
    self.title = [imageDict objectForKey:@"title"];
    self.image = [imageDict objectForKey:@"image"];
}
```

it really is messy.

The correct way to do it would be to create an array to `CardContainerData` transformer, which would basically wrap the same code but encapsulate it more cleanly.

Comment: Hello @Wain, thank you for your answer, i understand that i want the contents of the array, but my question is how can i get this in the container? I have a Container class who is an NSArray, and i want to get the container_awards, and i don't understand how to do that. I have the mapping class for the (title and image), but it's inside an three dimensional array. I can't change the response of the server.

Comment: Why is your container class 'an' array? Why don't you have an array property which will contain a number of instances of your container class?

Comment: Sorry, my class container have a property of an NSArray.

Comment: `Card` has a property `data` of type `CardContainerArray`, but that isn't really an array. From there you try to map into an `NSArray`, but you should really just have an `NSArray` property that you map instances of, probably, `CardContainer` class.

Comment: This is mi Card class: class CardContainerArray;
interface Card : NSObject


property(nonatomic,strong) NSString *image;
property(nonatomic,strong) CardContainerArray *data; And this is my CardContainerArray class: interface CardContainerArray : NSObject

property(nonatomic,strong) NSArray *container;

end

Comment: Add code to the questions, it's basically unreadable in a  comment. Why do you have `containers` in your mapping, that does't match any JSON or properties you've mentioned - typo?

Comment: Take a second to learn how to format code, you'll get a lot more / better answers in future ;-) Your classes look workable, the problem really is the JSON `[[[{"title":"","image":""}]]]` - why are there so many arrays - is it always like that?

Comment: Ok! :) In this case is like that, and i know is not the best way but i can't change the response. The problem is how to tell rest kit that "parse" the three dimensional array, and put the result in container_award.